# In knockoutjs after loading json data the ui becomes unresponsive

Tags: knockout.js

This occurs in nested items.
The code can be seen here.
http://jsfiddle.net/PxULV/3/

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the mapping plugin to work correctly you should try to ensure that the collections you are mapping are created by the mapping plugin in the first instance. When the mapping plugin runs it creates special mappedObservableArrays that it can then subsequently update.

You were also specifying the fromJSON method without any mapping information. The plugin therefore just created anonymous objects for the persons/children collections. It wasn't instructed to create Person objects.

I've got a working example here.

http://jsfiddle.net/madcapnmckay/Nje3S/

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes this was the response I was looking for. 
Thank you very much. You saved my day!

Answer (score -1):

I think you were just missing the Knockout mapping plugin. You also need to define the "a" variable as a regular JavaScript object instead of a string (remove the single-quotes surrounding it).

Sorry, but I can't find a way to link to the mapping plugin in a JsFiddle.

Comment: Sorry, looks like you did have the mapping plugin referenced. Try the other suggestion of making your "a" variable into an object. http://jsfiddle.net/PxULV/4/

Comment: Thanks for your response Tuan. The other suggestion saved my day.